# How to reload the api url in ionic2

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

After post the data to api url.I want to refresh the api url to get the last updated data

i have called my like this

```
this.http.get('api url here',{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                this.items=data;
            },
            err => {
                console.log('Err!')
            });
```

please give any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

add on Provider:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class ServiceProvider {

 baseUrl: string = 'https://...';

 constructor(public http: Http) {
  this.http = http;
 }

 getPosts(){
 return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .toPromise();// executa uma function e retorna JSON
 }
```

Then on Home:

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.getPostsSite();
 }

 getPostsSite(){
   this.serviceProvider.getPosts().then(
     response => { 
       this.items = response.data.children
   });

 }
```

Comment: I updated the answer. The function is executed in ngOnInit (). And it returns nothing

Comment: If you continue with doubts see this link: [Ionic 2 Mobile App in Under 60 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilM8YorL_jI)

Comment: Thank you instead ngOnInit we can use ionViewWillEnter()